# Rendering in-app message after receiving 200 response w/Webhook API Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue where I get the correct response and create the record in the database, but I am unable to show a success message with the json response inside of another controller/view. The create.js.erb action is working one-way only. I simply would like to update the message count and show an alert when the webhook is successful w/Twilio in the view that the message belongs to (conversation). How can I get the webhook to activate an alert/notice and replace with the size count in the view of the conversation? My code is below

**webhooks/twilio_controller.rb**

```
class Webhooks::TwilioController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity
include ApplicationHelper

def create
  provider = PersonalInfo.find_by(mobile_phone: params[:From])
  body = params[:Body]

 conversation = Conversation.find_or_create_by(personal_info: provider)
 message = conversation.messages.create(personal_info: provider, body: body)

respond_to do |format|
 format.json {render json: message} // would love to render status 200 and also activate alert in conversation view that response was made
format.js
 end
 end
end
```

**messages/create.js.erb**

```
$('#conversation_msg_count_<%= @message.conversation.messages.size %>').text('<%= @message.conversation.messages.size %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**webhooks/twilio_controller.rb**
create @message in the database

```
@notice = "" # will hold notification on either success or error
@messages = "" # will hold messages query
@message = conversation.messages.new(personal_info: provider, body: body)
respond_to do |format|
 if(@message.save)
  @notice = "NOTICE HERE"
  @messages = conversation.messages # FIND_MESSAGES_BEFORE CALLING MESSAGE INSTANCE COUNT IN create.js.erb
  format.js {template: 'messages/create.js.erb'}
end
```

**messages/create.js.erb**

```
$('#conversation_msg_count_<%= @messages.conversation.messages.size %>').text('<%= @messages.conversation.messages.size %>');
$('.notice-div').html('<% j @notice %> %>').show(1000); // show notice in html.erb
setTimeout(function(){$('.notice-div').hide(2000)}, 3000); // hide notice-div after 3 seconds
```

**messages.html.erb**

```
<div class='notice-div'></div>
```

Style your .notice-div in your css file to the way you want your notices to look like.